# YouTube embed that scales up when played - how did Google do this?

Tags: html, youtube, embed, containers

See [this Google support page](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2999770?hl=en&ref_topic=3175091) for reference. They have an embedded YouTube video that is responsive and when you click it it expands to a comfortable viewing size (704x396?). But in its default state it is nice and compact (400x230px), not hogging real estate for viewers who are focused on the text content. In its expanded state there is an X button to exit the expanded state and pause the video.

This is an awesome way to present embedded video content for obvious reasons, but no such configuration options are offered by YouTube when you generate an embed link. This is something unique to Google's support pages. I want to do the same for a page I have with an embedded video, but I don't really understand which div(s) are responsible for this or how they're doing it.

The relevant HTML is somewhere in here:

```
<div class="html5-video-container">

<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" style="width: 400px; height: 230px; left: 0px; top: -230px; transform: none;"></video>

<div class="html5-video-content" style="width: 400px; height: 230px; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
    <div class="video-annotations iv-module">
        <div class="video-legacy-annotations html5-stop-propagation"></div>
        <div class="video-custom-annotations"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="countdowntimer hid iv-module" style="display: none;"><svg width="60" height="60"><g><circle class="countdowntimer-background-circle" cx="30" cy="30" r="15"></circle><path class="countdowntimer-diminishing-pieslice" d="M30,30 z"></path><circle class="countdowntimer-middle-dot" cx="30" cy="30" r="4"></circle></g></svg>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="html5-storyboard-framepreview" aria-hidden="true" style="display: none;"><img class="html5-storyboard-framepreview-img" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7" style="width: 400px; height: 225px; margin: 2px 0px 3px; background: url(https://i.ytimg.com/sb/bxREkVhzEkw/storyboard3_L1/M0.jpg?sigh=Mc8I4tT3lUDa1DyySVXfnCowNkw) 0px 0px / 4000px 2250px;">
</div>

<canvas width="60" height="60" class="html5-video-loader html5-center-overlay ytp-scalable-icon-grow" style="display: none; transform: scale(0.5);" aria-hidden="true"></canvas>

<div class="ytp-thumbnail html5-stop-propagation" style="background-image: url(https://i.ytimg.com/vi_webp/bxREkVhzEkw/hqdefault.webp);">
    <div class="ytp-large-play-button html5-center-overlay ytp-scalable-icon-shrink" style="transform: scale(0.638888888888889);"><svg><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#1F1F1F" class="ytp-large-play-button-svg" d="M84.15,26.4v6.35c0,2.833-0.15,5.967-0.45,9.4c-0.133,1.7-0.267,3.117-0.4,4.25l-0.15,0.95c-0.167,0.767-0.367,1.517-0.6,2.25c-0.667,2.367-1.533,4.083-2.6,5.15c-1.367,1.4-2.967,2.383-4.8,2.95c-0.633,0.2-1.316,0.333-2.05,0.4c-0.767,0.1-1.3,0.167-1.6,0.2c-4.9,0.367-11.283,0.617-19.15,0.75c-2.434,0.034-4.883,0.067-7.35,0.1h-2.95C38.417,59.117,34.5,59.067,30.3,59c-8.433-0.167-14.05-0.383-16.85-0.65c-0.067-0.033-0.667-0.117-1.8-0.25c-0.9-0.133-1.683-0.283-2.35-0.45c-2.066-0.533-3.783-1.5-5.15-2.9c-1.033-1.067-1.9-2.783-2.6-5.15C1.317,48.867,1.133,48.117,1,47.35L0.8,46.4c-0.133-1.133-0.267-2.55-0.4-4.25C0.133,38.717,0,35.583,0,32.75V26.4c0-2.833,0.133-5.95,0.4-9.35l0.4-4.25c0.167-0.966,0.417-2.05,0.75-3.25c0.7-2.333,1.567-4.033,2.6-5.1c1.367-1.434,2.967-2.434,4.8-3c0.633-0.167,1.333-0.3,2.1-0.4c0.4-0.066,0.917-0.133,1.55-0.2c4.9-0.333,11.283-0.567,19.15-0.7C35.65,0.05,39.083,0,42.05,0L45,0.05c2.467,0,4.933,0.034,7.4,0.1c7.833,0.133,14.2,0.367,19.1,0.7c0.3,0.033,0.833,0.1,1.6,0.2c0.733,0.1,1.417,0.233,2.05,0.4c1.833,0.566,3.434,1.566,4.8,3c1.066,1.066,1.933,2.767,2.6,5.1c0.367,1.2,0.617,2.284,0.75,3.25l0.4,4.25C84,20.45,84.15,23.567,84.15,26.4z M33.3,41.4L56,29.6L33.3,17.75V41.4z"></path><polygon fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" fill="#FFFFFF" points="33.3,41.4 33.3,17.75 56,29.6"></polygon></svg>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="html5-bezel html5-center-overlay" style="display: none;">
    <div class="html5-bezel-play"></div>
</div>
```

The CSS and javascript I'm not sure about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the HTML you posted really does what you think. YouTube's HTML that is inside the embedded iframe is designed to proportionally fit inside the iframe node.

To answer your question though, they simply just use JavaScript to change embedded iframe's height and width. Inside the reference link you posted, inspect the youtube player, and find the iframe node, and watch the inline styling as you play/close the youtube player.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to accept your answer for so long. And thank you!